# use ssh private key from host in vagrant guest

Tags: vagrant

I want to clone a bunch of private git repositories while provisioning a vagrant box. According to [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/q8z1rg) this should be possible using `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`. However, when trying to connect to github via something like `ssh -T git@github.com -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` it fails with the following error:

> Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

I cut my configuration down to the simplest possible configuration. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/TomTasche/31f7c45fcffc2997d43a

When I do "vagrant ssh" and try the same again, a similar error occurs:

> Cloning into 'private-repositories'...
>   Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

**Edit:** the configuration linked above does work on a host running Ubuntu, but does neither work on a Mac host, nor on a Windows host. My goal is to have a configuration that works on all these three hosts.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please check whether your host system has ssh-agent forwarding enabled. You can do so for example by adding this block to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host                    *
  ForwardAgent          yes
```

If this is enabled `vagrant ssh` (and also `vagrant provision`) should be able to forward your key to the guest machine.

You also might want to check using `ssh-add -l` whether your ssh-agent does know about your SSH-key. If it is in the list and you have agent-forwarding activated you should have a success. Otherwise you can add the key to your ssh-agent by running `ssh-add <path to your key file>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After following the above instructions I'm able to authenticate via ssh in `vagrant ssh`. However, my provisioning script still fails, with the following error: `Error reading response length from authentication socket.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Yeah a few days ago we experienced that in the office too… It continued to work at some time without real action… The documentation says `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` combined with ssh-agent forwarding should work but we didn't managed to find why it didn't work… :/

Comment: Meh, that kind of destroys the whole concept of moving my dev environment into a container if it doesn't work on all platforms. Anyway, thanks for your help! Maybe someone else comes up with a solution...

Comment: Thanks dude, your answer works perfectly on both Linux and Mac. Windows does not work as expected, but @Tim Donohue has a solution for that!

Comment: This practice is strongly recommended against by Github!

"Warning: You may be tempted to use a wildcard like Host * to just apply this setting to all SSH connections. That's not really a good idea, as you'd be sharing your local SSH keys with every server you SSH into. They won't have direct access to the keys, but they will be able to use them as you while the connection is established. You should only add servers you trust and that you intend to use with agent forwarding."

https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

Comment: Thank you very match. It works in vagrant provision only if 'git clone' started as vagrant user. Vagrant provision does not work if uses default root user or any other user. Make sure you add in your cloning script option: user 'vagrant'

Comment: Worked for me as well after some additional config. In my case connections have to go through a proxy, so I had to setup the proxy config from my local ~/.ssh/config file in the Vagrant box.

Comment: @envision pointed out that Github recommends against the wildcard. But thinking into it, why would this really be a security concern? It says that the servers will not have access to the keys, so the keys are not compromised. And it only takes effect during the login session. And it's only used when you run commands that need the keys. If you don't use this method, you might have a provision in place with a unique key for the server, where there will be the same final effect. In most cases, people are probably familiar with the servers they are SSH'ing into... Where is the real concern?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you may be hitting this particular bug:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735
(Despite it being "closed" it's actually not *fixed*)

On Windows, SSH Forwarding in Vagrant does not work properly by default (because of a bug in net-ssh).

However, there is a workaround or simple hack. You can auto-copy your local SSH key to the Vagrant VM via a simple provisioning script in your VagrantFile. Here's an example:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735#issuecomment-25640783

Comment: I'd love to split the bounty between you and @Knut, but his answer allowed me to get SSH Agent Forwarding running on both Mac and Linux. Your answer is spot on for Windows though! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Tom,

What you're doing is fairly generic in nature and I don't think is `Vagrant` specific.

Try some of the following to track down the issue:

1. edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Set `LogLevel debug`
3. Restart the sshd service `sudo service sshd restart` or `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`
4. `tail -f /var/log/authlog` -- note, the file may be something else like `/var/log/authd.log` or `/var/log/secure` or something.
5. Watch what happens when you connect.  It should give you some indication of why it's failing.

Again sorry, I'm not that familiar with `Vagrant` but I'm wondering if the provisioning script is running as another user, in which case the agent forwarding may not work as expected?

Comment: The provisioning script is ran as root as far as I know. This seems to be the cause of my problem actually, but proposed workarounds do not work either: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1303

Comment: the file is /var/log/auth.log on Ubuntu 14.04 if anyone has a problem